# How do I add multiple ComponentDialogs?

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service

I made a new ComponentDialog by creating a class for it that extends `ComponentDialog` like so:

```cs
public class GetPersonInfoDialog : ComponentDialog
{
        protected readonly ILogger Logger;

        public GetPersonInfoDialog(IConfiguration configuration, ILogger<GetPersonInfoDialog> logger)
            : base("get-person-info", configuration["ConnectionName"])
        { }
        // code ommitted
    }
}
```

Then I added it in Startup.cs:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        // ...

        services.AddSingleton<GreetingDialog>();
        services.AddTransient<IBot, AuthBot<GreetingDialog>>();

        // My new component dialog:
        services.AddSingleton<GetPersonInfoDialog>();
        services.AddTransient<IBot, AuthBot<GetPersonInfoDialog>>();
    }
}
```

But what I noticed is that only the last Dialog gets used. GreetingDialog now no longer works, saying:

> DialogContext.BeginDialogAsync(): A dialog with an id of 'greeting' wasn't found. The dialog must be included in the current or parent DialogSet. For example, if subclassing a ComponentDialog you can call AddDialog() within your constructor.

I did notice, however, that the GetPersonInfo dialog does indeed begin and the Greeting dialog doesn't anymore. It's like I can only use one or the other. I noticed only the last added "transient" gets used, as if it overrides the previous transients.

How do I add **multiple component dialogs** in my Startup.cs file? Or am I even going about this correctly? I did not find any documentation explaining how to have multiple ComponentDialogs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**In Startup.cs**

I will start with your `Startup.cs` file since that is where the first issue is, then I will suggest an alternative design.

What you are effectively doing with the following block of code is:

```
services.AddSingleton<GreetingDialog>();
services.AddTransient<IBot, AuthBot<GreetingDialog>>();

services.AddSingleton<GetPersonInfoDialog>();
services.AddTransient<IBot, AuthBot<GetPersonInfoDialog>>();
```

1. Registering a single instance of the `GreetingDialog` for your bot (essentially a static).
2. Registering the `IBot` interface to return a new `AuthBot` of type `GreetingDialog` *everytime* an `IBot` is requested.
3. Registering a single instance of the `GetPersonInfoDialog` for your bot (essentially a static).
4. Registering the `IBot` interface (again) to return a new `AuthBot` of type `GetPersonInfoDialog` everytime an `IBot` is requested (which will overwrite the registration in step 2).

You can read a lot more about Service lifetimes [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2#service-lifetimes).

So what you actually want is more like the below:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Other code

    // Register dialogs
    services.AddTransient<GreetingDialog>();
    services.AddTransient<GetPersonInfoDialog>();

    // Some more code

    // Configure bot
    services.AddTransient<IBot, DialogBot<GreetingDialog>>();
}
```

---

**Error message**

> DialogContext.BeginDialogAsync(): A dialog with an id of 'greeting'
>   wasn't found. The dialog must be included in the current or parent
>   DialogSet. For example, if subclassing a ComponentDialog you can call
>   AddDialog() within your constructor.

This error message is caused because your `GetPersonInfoDialog` doesn't know about your `GreetingDialog` (and it shouldn't). I believe this is a runtime error because I remember running into a similar issue myself. Since you haven't provided the full implementation for your `GetPersonInfoDialog` class I have to assume that somewhere inside there you are trying to do something like the following:

```
dialogContext.BeginDialogAsync("greeting");

or

dialogContext.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(GreetingDialog));
```

as per [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.dialogs.dialogcontext.begindialogasync?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable) the first parameter is the *ID of the dialog to start*, this ID is also used to retrieve the dialog from the dialog stack. In order to call one dialog from inside another, you will need to add it to the parent dialog's `DialogSet`. The accepted way to do this is to add a call inside the constructor for the parent dialog like so:

```
public ParentDialog(....)
    : base(nameof(ParentDialog)
{
    // Some code

    // Important part
    AddDialog(new ChildDialog(nameof(ChildDialog)));
}
```

This uses the [AddDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.dialogs.componentdialog.adddialog?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable#Microsoft_Bot_Builder_Dialogs_ComponentDialog_AddDialog_Microsoft_Bot_Builder_Dialogs_Dialog_) method provided by the Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs NuGet package and exposed through the `ComponentDialog` class.

Then when you want to display the `ChildDialog` you would call:

```
dialogContext.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(ChildDialog));
```

In your case you can replace `ParentDialog` with `GetPersonInfoDialog` and `ChildDialog` with `GreetingDialog`. Since your `GreetingDialog` is only likely to be used once (it is not a utility dialog that could be called multiple times but with different arguments - in this case you would want to provide a specific ID rather than using `nameof(GreetingDialog)`) it is fine to go with the string representation of the class name as the DialogId, you can using "greeting" inside the the `AddDialog` call but you would also have to update the `BeginDialogAsync` call to also use "greeting".

---

**An alternative design**

Since I don't believe you want either `GreetingDialog` or `GetPersonInfoDialog` to be your actual starting points, I would suggest adding another dialog called `MainDialog` which inherits from the `RouterDialog` class (Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Solutions.Dialogs NuGet package). Based on the architecture (Virtual Assistant Template) [here](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions/blob/master/templates/Virtual-Assistant-Template/csharp/Sample/VirtualAssistantSample/Dialogs/MainDialog.cs) you would have your `MainDialog` spawn off your `GreetingDialog` and `GetPersonInfoDialog`.

Assuming that your `GreetingDialog` is only a single stage where it sends a card or some text to the user to welcome them,  it could be completely replaced by the `OnStartAsync` method which sends your card/message. Getting your user to your `GetPersonInfoDialog` would then be handled by the `RouteAsync` method [example here](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions/blob/master/templates/Virtual-Assistant-Template/csharp/Sample/VirtualAssistantSample/Dialogs/MainDialog.cs#L77).

The changes you would need to make to your existing project to get this wired up are (assuming that you keep the `GreetingDialog`):

- Add Transient registrations in `Startup.cs` for `GreetingDialog`, `GetPersonInfoDialog` and `MainDialog`.
- Add a Transient registration for mapping `IBot` to `AuthBot<MainDialog>`
- Add calls inside the constructor of `MainDialog` to add the child dialogs `GreetingDialog` and `GetPersonInfoDialog`.
- In the `OnBeginDialog` or `OnStartAsync` of `MainDialog` start your `GreetingDialog`.
- In the `RouteAsync` of `MainDialog` handle any conditions around showing the `GetPersonInfoDialog` before displaying it.
- There may be some additional steps that I have missed.

Helpful links:

- [Implementing sequential conversation flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-dialog-manage-conversation-flow?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp).
- [Reusing dialogs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-compositcontrol?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp).
- [Virtual Assistant template outline](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions/blob/master/docs/reference/assistant/templateoutline.md)
- [Virtual Assistant template architecture](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions/blob/master/docs/reference/assistant/underthecovers.md).

---

**Edit**

To achieve what you want within the [OAuth sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/18.bot-authentication) you could do the following:

In *LogoutDialog.cs* change:

```
private async Task<DialogTurnResult> InterruptAsync(DialogContext innerDc, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
```

to

```
protected virtual async Task<DialogTurnResult> InterruptAsync(DialogContext innerDc, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
```

In *MainDialog.cs* add:

```
protected override async Task<DialogTurnResult> InterruptAsync(DialogContext innerDc, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
{
    if (innerDc.Context.Activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
    {
        var text = innerDc.Context.Activity.Text.ToLowerInvariant();

        if (text == "check email")
        {
            //
            return innerDc.BeginDialogAsync(/*TODO*/);
        }
        else if (text == "check calender")
        {
            //
            return innerDc.BeginDialogAsync(/*TODO*/);
        }
        // etc


        return await base.InterruptAsync(innerDc, cancellationToken);
    }

    return null;
}
```

along with registering your Calendar, Email, etc dialogs in the constructor for `MainDialog` using the `AddDialog` method.

**I would seriously advise you to look at using the [Virtual Assistant Template](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions/blob/master/docs/tutorials/csharp/virtualassistant.md).** As it uses [LUIS](https://luis.ai/home) to determing the user's intent (check email, check calendar etc), then route them accordingly, the relevant code is in [this method](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions/blob/master/templates/Virtual-Assistant-Template/csharp/Sample/VirtualAssistantSample/Dialogs/MainDialog.cs#L77). Using LUIS to determine intents has the advantage of being able to tie multiple ways of asking the same thing to the same intent, so you're not relying on your users to explicitly type "check calendar", you can have "show me my calendar", "what is my availability for next Monday", "am I free this afternoon", "check if I have any appointments tomorrow" etc. In fact Microsoft has already built [Skills](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions/blob/master/docs/readme.md#skills-1) for email, and calendar which work with the Virtual Assistant Template, it should be easy enough to port the login code over to this template.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'll be honest... this is very complicated to me. We plan to have many dialogs the user can have, like ask for their emails, ask for info on an employee, check their calendar, check the menu in our cafeteria, etc. So I would need a `switch` case to determine which dialog to run. Would this switch statement go in the MainDialog, and I wouldn't make a singleton for them? FYI I already have MainDialog because I started with their [OAuth](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/18.bot-authentication) sample.

Comment: I have added an edit to the end of my answer of how to handle this, and yes no singletons, make your Dialogs `Transient`.

Comment: AAaah! Thank you very much sir! I plan to also look at the virtual assistant template as well!

Comment: No problem, best of luck! It can be quite intimidating at first with all of the stuff in there but I'm sure you'll get your head around it.