# How to call various child dialog from dialogBot.cs?

Tags: c#, botframework

I have created a dispatcher, on getting a value of particular intent I called a child dialog as shown below:

```
if (topIntent == "NewRequest")
{
    await dc.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(RequestForm));
    // await dc.BeginDialogAsync("RequestForm",null,cancellationToken);
} else if(topIntent == "Mailbox")
{
    await MaiboxAsync(dc, cancellationToken);
}

protected async Task MaiboxAsync(DialogContext dc, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
{
    await dc.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(MailboxAccessForm));
}
```

Whenever the top intent is new request or mailbox I get this error:

> Error: Exception caught : DialogContext.BeginDialogAsync(): A dialog with an id of 'requestForm' wasn't found. The dialog must be included in the current or parent DialogSet

I have added the dialogs in DialogBot.cs file as shown below:

```
public class DialogBot<T> : ActivityHandler where T : Dialog
{
    protected readonly Dialog Dialog;
    // protected readonly BotState ConversationState;
    protected readonly BotState UserState;
    protected readonly ILogger Logger;
    private IBotServices BotServices;
    private IEnumerable<WaterfallStep> waterfallSteps;
    private ConversationState ConversationState;

    // private DialogSet _dialogs;
    private DialogSet Dialogs { get; set; }
    // private IConfiguration configuration;

    public DialogBot(IBotServices botServices, ConversationState conversationState, UserState userState, T dialog, ILogger<DialogBot<T>> logger)
    {
        ConversationState = conversationState;
        UserState = userState;
        Dialog = dialog;
        Logger = logger;
        BotServices = botServices;
        RegisterDialogs();
        Dialogs = new DialogSet(conversationState.CreateProperty<DialogState>(nameof(DialogBot<T>)));

        Dialogs.Add(new WaterfallDialog("MainDialog", new WaterfallStep[]
        {
            async (dc, cancellationToken) =>
            {
                // Start the ChoiceFlowDialog that was loaded earlier
                // This will take the conversation through the 
                // 'waterfall' steps defined in the choiceFlow.json file
                    return await dc.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(RequestForm));
            }
        }));
     }

    private void RegisterDialogs()
    {
        Dialogs = new DialogSet(ConversationState.CreateProperty<DialogState>                (nameof(DialogBot<T>)));
        Dialogs.Add(new WaterfallDialog("CreateTeamForm", waterfallSteps));
        Dialogs.Add(new WaterfallDialog("DistributionListForm", waterfallSteps));
        Dialogs.Add(new WaterfallDialog("FeedbackForm", waterfallSteps));
        Dialogs.Add(new WaterfallDialog("LicenseRequestForm", waterfallSteps));
        Dialogs.Add(new WaterfallDialog("MailboxAccessForm", waterfallSteps));
        Dialogs.Add(new WaterfallDialog("RequestForm", waterfallSteps));
        Dialogs.Add(new WaterfallDialog("ServiceNowIncidentCreation", waterfallSteps));
        Dialogs.Add(new WaterfallDialog("SharedMailboxForm", waterfallSteps));
    }
}
```

In my startup.cs class I made these following changes:

```
services.AddTransient<IBot, DialogBot<MainDialog>>();
services.AddTransient<RequestFormForm>();
services.AddTransient<MailboxAccessForm>();
```

Where am I going wrong?

I have gone through some similar link on Stack Overflow but none of them resolved my issue.

https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions/blob/master/templates/Virtual-Assistant-Template/csharp/Sample/VirtualAssistantSample/Dialogs/MainDialog.cs#L77

[How do I add multiple ComponentDialogs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56711455/how-do-i-add-multiple-componentdialogs)

Comment: Not sure if this was intended but you have in your `Startup.cs` `services.AddTransient<RequestFormForm>();`, this might be a spelling mistake. It's weird that it's saying id `requestForm` wasn't found because all the rest of your `RequestForm` are uppercase. Can you look in your code for the lowercase version `requestForm` and replace it with `RequestForm`?

Answer (score 0):

You get an error like

> Error: Exception caught : DialogContext.BeginDialogAsync(): A dialog with an id of "yourDialog" wasn't found.

any time that your dialogs aren't properly added to the DialogSet. Ensure that whenever you're calling a dialog, it has previously been added to the DialogSet somewhere in the code that has already executed. In your case, it's likely that you call this two separate times:

```cs
Dialogs = new DialogSet(conversationState.CreateProperty<DialogState>(nameof(DialogBot<T>)));
```

You're calling it once in the `DialogBot` constructor (as you should) and then again in `RegisterDialogs` (you shouldn't). Instead, you might want to do something like:

```cs
Dialogs = new DialogSet(conversationState.CreateProperty<DialogState>(nameof(DialogBot<T>)));
RegisterDialogs();

[...]
private void RegisterDialogs(DialogSet dialogs)
{
    Dialogs.Add(new CreateTeamForm(UserState));
    [...]
}
```

It's also possible that your RequestForm Dialog isn't passing the same name with something like:

```cs
public RequestForm(....)
    : base(nameof(RequestForm)
```

I also notice that sometimes you're using `"RequestForm"` and sometimes you're using `nameof(RequestForm)`. Better to stick with something consistent (I prefer `nameof(RequestForm)`)

---

Now that I've seen your code, I'll point out some other issues. It appears you're trying to merge some of the [old methods of adding dialogs](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/4.2.1-VSIX/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/13.basic-bot/BasicBot.cs#L62) with some of the [newer methods](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/13.core-bot/Startup.cs#L38). Best to just stick to one. For your code, I'd just stick to the older method. One of the big issues with what you're trying to do is that in `DialogBot`, every Dialog uses the same `waterfallSteps`, which hasn't been defined. Then, within each dialog, you're using `AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog(nameof(WaterfallDialog), waterfallSteps));`. So you're adding the same `WaterfallDialog` to each dialog. The last `AddDialog` that gets called is going to overwrite the others.

To get started fixing your code:

1. Remove the `AddTransient<XYZDialog/Form>` from `startup.cs`
2. Use the code I edited above to register each of your dialogs
3. You'll need to change the `UserState`  to `UserState` type and not `BotState`

That being said, I highly, highly recommend:

1. Downloading either the [old Basic Bot](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/4.2.1-VSIX/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/13.basic-bot) or [the new Core Bot](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/13.core-bot/)
2. Read through it and make sure you understand exactly how the Dialogs are being called and constructed
3. You may also consider re-writing your bot to use either the new or old style--but sticking to just one style--and testing each dialog after you add it. I think part of the reason that your issue was difficult to track down is that you added too much, too fast, without testing in between.

Comment: @rahuljha Assuming LUIS/QnA is returning the correct `topIntent`, there's likely something wrong with your DialogSet or switch statement. Can you post a link to your code or send to vDASHmicricATmicrosoftDOTcom (replacing all-caps with appropriate character)?

Comment: i have copied my code to : https://github.com/rahuljha819/jharahul/blob/master/DispatcherCombinedTrial.zip              To test the code please type "create new team" it should go to "TeamsCreation" intent further it should start "CreateTeamForm"      Also,    while debugging the code i found that the code was routing to "MainDialog.cs" file but the value of stepContext.Result is null . so, i am not sure why the stepContext returning the null value?

Comment: @rahuljha Might want to delete that repo. You still had your QnA and LUIS keys in your appsettings.

Comment: @rahuljha I've updated my answer to reflect reviewing your code.

Comment: 1. Thank u, I did the changes as mentioned by you, but the child dialogs doesn't gets completed, on next question it goes back to disptacher in dialogbot.cs and returns "None" intent             
  2. Yes I'll delete the code for testing purpose I gave you

Comment: @rahuljha Those fixes were only meant to get you started. There are a LOT of issues with your code regarding how it constructs and calls dialogs. I really, really do recommend following the last 3 steps I mentioned. Unfortunately, there is not a quick fix for this.

Comment: Dialogs are a bit confusing. IMHO it doesn't align with DI principles and the "AddDialog" registration is kind of nasty for beginners. Not to mention the dialog instance lifecycles (e.g. are they singleton or transient etc.).

Sorry about the ads here but I was trying to make this simpler for starters especially those who want to build some simple scenarios. If you are interested, [check this out](https://github.com/sidecus/zyin.intentbot).